# C# Multiplying the values of an array together which are loaded from a textfile into a List<>

Tags: c#, arrays, filereader, streamreader

So I have an array, strArray, that stores the values of my text files which has 3 columns. I think this is called a two or three dimensional array, not sure. Or maybe one dimensional. I have a List<> called Inventory which adds the data to it.

I currently have three successful columns I just need the fourth. The fourth column is the second and third column multiplied together, which is a total price. The second column is an int, "Number of Items", the third is a decimal, "Price" and the fourth is a decimal, "Total Price" which is Number of Items * Price.

I'll go ahead and post my code, **I am also using four list boxes for the data**. Three columns (or three list boxes) work fine, but I just gotta get the fourth one figured out.

Sorry for the large amount of code, I figured if I copied all of it it'll make it easier to see if an error occurred earlier on. **btnLoadInfo_Click is the event/method where the main issue is.**

```
namespace TCSCapstone
{
public partial class frmInventory : Form
{
    List<frmInventory> Inventory = new List<frmInventory>();

    public frmInventory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfItems { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    string selectedList = "";

    private void cmbList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedList = this.cmbList.GetItemText(this.cmbList.SelectedItem);

        lstItemName.DataSource = null;
        lstNumberOfItems.DataSource = null;
        lstPrice.DataSource = null;

        lstItemName.Items.Clear();
        lstNumberOfItems.Items.Clear();
        lstPrice.Items.Clear();
        lstTotalPrices.Items.Clear();

        if (selectedList == "Creative Construction")//if the selected combo box item equals the exact string selected
        {
            selectedList = "creative"; //then the string equals creative, which is creative.txt but I add the .txt in the btnLoadInfo method
        } else if (selectedList == "Paradise Building")
        {
            selectedList = "paradise";//this is for paradise.txt
        }
        else if (selectedList == "Sitler Construction")
        {
            selectedList = "sitler";//this is for sitler.txt
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select one of the items.");
        }
    }`



        private void btnLoadInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Inventory.Clear(); //Clears the entire Inventory List

         using (StreamReader invReader = new StreamReader(selectedList + 
 ".txt"))
         {
             while (invReader.Peek() >= 0)
             {
                 string str;
                 string[] strArray;
                 str = invReader.ReadLine();

                 strArray = str.Split(',');
                 frmInventory currentItem = new frmInventory();

                 currentItem.ItemName = strArray[0];
                 currentItem.NumberOfItems = int.Parse(strArray[1]);
                 currentItem.Price = 
 decimal.Parse(strArray[2]);

                 strArray[1].
                 currentItem.TotalPrice = decimal.Parse(strArray[1] * 
strArray[2]);

                 Inventory.Add(currentItem);

             }
         }


         displayLists(); //Calls the displayLists method to update list 
//boxes at the end of the button click event
     }//end of btnLoadInfo

     void displayLists()
     {
         //Resets the listboxes datasources by setting them to null
         lstItemName.DataSource = null;
         lstNumberOfItems.DataSource = null;
         lstPrice.DataSource = null;

         lstItemName.Items.Clear();
         lstNumberOfItems.Items.Clear();
         lstPrice.Items.Clear();
         lstTotalPrices.Items.Clear();

         lstItemName.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
         lstItemName.ValueMember = "";
         lstItemName.DataSource = Inventory;

         lstNumberOfItems.DisplayMember = "NumberOfItems";
         lstNumberOfItems.ValueMember = "";
         lstNumberOfItems.DataSource = Inventory;

         lstPrice.DisplayMember = "Price";
         lstPrice.ValueMember = "";
         lstPrice.DataSource = Inventory;
     }
```

Comment: Aside from the random `strArray[1].` sitting there, what is the actual issue?

Comment: Also, you already have the values of `strArray[1]` and 2 pulled into an int and decimal, respectively, so it would not make much sense to try to parse them again (nor to try to multiply two strings together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to multiply two strings together. Instead, multiply the numeric values that you have already parsed:

```
currentItem.TotalPrice = currentItem.NumberOfItems * currentItem.Price;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the solution I needed. I overthought it, I had all the data I needed literally above this. Thanks again :)

Comment: Actually what you need to do is make your TotalPrice property a get (read only) that does the multiplication. Right now you have an object that allows you to have ten $5 items for a TotalPrice of 79.99, or 7.62.. Or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your TotalPrice property should be a mathematical equation, not something you set independently of the number of items and their prices.

Change the property to this:

```
public decimal TotalPrice{
  get{ return NumberOfItems * Price; }
}
```

Delete the line that sets TotalPrice in your loop; it's no longer necessary because you've set the item price and the number of items; the total price inherently follows from these